# Rows in ListView inflating one upon another

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's the necessary code. I'm trying to use two different views for rows within the same listview. I want one set of arraylist to be inflated as row, and then another. But what happens is the rows get inflated one upon another.

Code :

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < (mContactsNumber.size())) {
            a = 0;
            return a;
        } else {
            a = 1;
            return a;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final int pos = i;
        int type = getItemViewType(i);
        View v = view;
        if (view == null) {
            switch (type) {
                case 0:
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_row, null);
                    name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
                    name.setText(mContactsNames.get(i));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.manual_row, null);
                    mManual = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.manual_number);
                    mSwitch = (SwitchCompat) v.findViewById(R.id.manual_switch);
                    mManual.setText(mPermanentManual.get(i));
                    mSwitch.setTag(i);
                    try {
                        if (mManualList.contains(mPermanentManual.get(i))) {
                            mSwitch.setChecked(true);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return v;
        }
```

Comment: You can check http://learnncode.co/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem occurs when `convertView` is not null because you don't have `else` statement in your `getView` method.

you could use `ItemViewType`

change your adapter to something like this :

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM_0 = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_ITEM_1 = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2;

       ...


        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return (position < (mContactsNumber.size()) ? TYPE_ITEM_0 : TYPE_ITEM_1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }


        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        ...
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM_0:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_ITEM_1:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Right. But what would I add in `else`, since everything is inflated and the Widgets are instantiated within `if` itself?

Comment: You can break it out into two methods based on the switch. Each can inflate or reuse the convertView and set the appropriate data.